# Did the MATLAB R2019a mxArray header change?

Tags: matlab, mex

I have MATLAB mex code that hacks into the mxArray header to read and modify fields such as the CrossLink pointer (used for shared data copies) etc.  This is necessary to allow me to work with very large variables inside mex routines without creating deep copies. This code works well up to R2018b but now crashes MATLAB. What has changed?

Comment: Thank you! Great information!

Comment: and as discussed elsewhere it looks like it has changed since. 2020b is clearly different for example ...

Answer (score 4):

The mxArray header has changed in R2019a. The location of the CrossLink field in the mxArray header has moved next to the reverse CrossLink field. So, the order for R2018b and earlier is this:

```
void *RevCrossLink;
mxClassID ClassID;
int VariableType;
mxArray *CrossLink;
    :
etc.
```

but for R2019a it is this

```
void *RevCrossLink;
mxArray *CrossLink;  <-- moved
mxClassID ClassID;
int VariableType;
    :
etc.
```

So if you want your code to be robust and compile/run under different MATLAB versions, you will need to programmatically determine the MATLAB version. C code to determine the MATLAB version at compile and run time can be found here:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/67016-c-mex-matlab-version